# Printing a PDF using vb.net and adobe Reader DC not working windows cannot find the application

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that has been working for a while, it basically prints a pdf file to default printer, i had to put this application on a newer pc with the win version 20h2 and now windows returns an error saying it can not find the application. not sure if its a microsoft thing or if my code can be modified to work with it. One constant has to stay in place, Adobe Reader DC has to remain the default PDF reader. below is the code snippet that does the printing , it has worked since january. now will not work with newer windows version.

```
Private Sub PrintDocument(src As String)
    Dim psi As New Process()
    psi.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    psi.StartInfo.Verb = "print"
    psi.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.StartInfo.FileName = src
    psi.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    psi.Start()

    psi.WaitForInputIdle()

    psi.CloseMainWindow()
    psi.Close()

    Thread.Sleep(10000)
    CheckAndCloseAdobeProcess()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that Adobe DC is set as the default PDF viewer in Windows ? That would explain the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The Windows update had probably change your default PDF reader, I guess edge is your new PDF reader.

Comment: i was working on this for a while yesterday and i saw adobe was set as default. and still bombed. i reinstalled adobe reader and its started working, i left that box alone and 2 hours later it threw the same error. I went and double checked it just now and its still set to adobe i fired up the app and its printing fine. im not sure what the hell is happening now. :/

Comment: i may have overlooked it. seems to be working. will mark as answer. thank you.